# Facebook Android hash key generates 25 characters instead of 29

Tags: facebook-android-sdk

I am using this below code to generate facebook Android hash key

```
$ keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Documents and 
Settings\Administrator.android\debug.keystore" | "C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" sha1 
-binary |"C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" base64
```

But it generates 25 characters key, It should be 29. Facebook allows to adding the key only if key length is 29.

Is that code correct?